# htpasswd protected folder with json file in returning 401 when fetching json

Tags: json, .htaccess, fetch, .htpasswd

I have a folder in a directory (/cars) which I have password protected using a .htaccess and .htpasswd file. For simplicity's sake I have two files in this folder: index.php and carsData.json. Within index.php I have some javascript which calls the carsData.json.

However I get the following error in the console:

`http://example.com/cars/carsData.json 401 (Authorization Required)`

I am prompted for the password when visiting the page which is accepted as it displays what is in index.php.

I can actually view the json in browser once I've put the password in by visiting http://example.com/cars/carsData.json directly.

Here is my javascript in case this is an issue:

```
fetch("carsData.json")
.then(response => response.json())
.then(function(carsData){
    getCarsData(carsData);
});
```

Everything works great locally and without the .htaccess / .htpasswd file. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to bypass when calling that json file from ajax or you can also send the creds in the ajax request

Comment: I’m not sure what you mean. The json file is at the same level as index.php.